# Digital Signature on WCF SOAP message

Tags: wcf, web-services

I've got a requirement to connect to a web service using a digital signature. I'm using .NET 4.0 and WCF (Service Reference), and X509 SSL certificate, but can't find any suitable instructions on how to properly accomplish the goal.

I've found hundreds and hundreds of posts and blogs, etc, on encrypting soap messages, signing data, and the lot, with numerous examples using everything from X509Certificate1, X509Certificate2, X509Certificate3, DSACryptoServiceProvider, RSACryptoServiceProvider, setting up config in the web.config, setting up the config in code, using basicHttpBinding, or wsHttpBinding, or using WSE, WSE2, WSE3, ad nauseum.

Basically, I've found all kinds of information that is completely useless to me, as I've not been able to find a single complete example of how to simply add a digital signature to a soap message.

It certainly sounds like it should be a simple process, by the reading of examples of what digital signatures are, but I can't find a single useful implementation.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: "connect to a web service using a digital signature". This sounds odd. Does this mean you need to attach a client certificate when calling that web service? What other info does that service host give you?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I don't really have much other than an address and a wsdl, and have traded certs with the host. I know that the service is written in Java and hosted via Apache CFX. The only errors I get back are that something in the header didnt jibe with the services expected header info. I can connect, but dont get much further than that.

Comment: You found many examples because there are many variants how to do that. You must know exactly what you want to achieve. Is the service already implemented? Does it have WS-SecurityPolicy assertions in WSDL describing how exactly the message must be signed? If yes, post that assertions to your question. If no go to service provider and ask for exact description of signed parts of messages.

Comment: Right on!  I agree all the samples and information available out there -- even from MSDN -- are completely useless.  S.O. has actually been the best, but look -- you didn't even get a decent answer...  My search continues..  It would be easier to just craft the damn SOAP request by hand.

Comment: This thread has been very good to me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666970/signing-soap-messages-using-x-509-certificate-from-wcf-service-to-java-webservic

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the security setup in the WCF binding. If you're just looking for the structure of your SOAP message, create a client using .NET and turn message logging on for the service. That will record every message being sent back and forth. I had to do this once, and found that the data encoding WCF uses (TLSNego) is proprietary, so a non-WCF client won't work.

Comment: Luckily, I have been able to get that running, but I don't ever see any signature info in the xml.

Comment: What type of security do you have on your binding? If it's message level you'll see a first message as RequestSecurityToken in the body with the "signature" as a base64binary data type.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer, but hopefully this might help someone who lands here...

Using WCF client to connect to a SOAP service that used WS-Security with digital signature on the messages means you have to use a custom client binding. Some of the details might vary depending on your service, for example, the service WSDL (or the service provider might tell you if you cannot get the WSDL) might define a different message security version, but I have made this work using a client configuration like this:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
            <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
                requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                requireSignatureConfirmation="false" canRenewSecurityContextToken="true">
                <secureConversationBootstrap defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"
                    authenticationMode="MutualSslNegotiated" requireDerivedKeys="true"
                    includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                    requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
                    <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
                    <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
                </secureConversationBootstrap>
                <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
                <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
            </security>
            <textMessageEncoding />
            <httpTransport />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```