# WCF Client With X.509 Certificate and Java Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, x509certificate

I'm currently trying to develop a client that interacts with a 3rd party web service.  The third party web service is written in Java, and we have supplied them with a CA X509 certificate that is used to sign the messages.  The 3rd party specifies WS-Security 1.1 (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-SOAPMessageSecurity.pdf).

We are able to successfully sign the message, send and get a response through SoapUI, but I am having trouble to get the same functionality to work in WCF (.NET 4.5).  I've looked at the message being sent from the WCF client (via SvcTraceViewer and the message logs), and it appears the format is slightly different from that in SoapUI.

When I send the message, I get the following exception:

`There was no endpoint listening at https://<service addres> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.`

The inner exception is `Unable to connect to the remote server`, and the inner exception for that is `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443`.

Since the endpoint is up and available, I'm thinking my binding is not set up entirely correctly.

I've checked questions here on SO, including [Signing SOAP messages using X.509 certificate from WCF service to Java webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4666970/745969) and read Yaron Naveh's [12 common wcf interop confusions](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html) which have helped, but haven't gotten me all the way there yet.

Binding defintion:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="myCustomBinding">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
              defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Sha256Rsa15"
              includeTimestamp="true"
              messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
              securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Method to create the proxy factory:

```
private Task<ChannelFactory<T>> CreateChannelFactory<T>(string bindingConfig, string address)
{

    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(address), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(<identity name>));
    ChannelFactory<T> proxy = new ChannelFactory<T>(new CustomBinding(bindingConfig), endpoint);
    proxy.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(storeLocation, storeName, findByType, findByValue);
    proxy.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(storeLocation, storeName, findByType, findByValue);

    return Task.FromResult<ChannelFactory<T>>(proxy);
}
```

The 3rd party actually has several services (one operation contract per service, essentially), so I generate `ChannelFactory<T>` objects for each service at client start using `async/await`, and the values `storeLocation`, `storeName`, `findByType` and `findByValue` for the certificate are stored globally in the client (in case any one was wondering).

When I send the message, I create a channel from the appropriate factory.  And then I get the error.

Here is the relevant part of the message sent via SoapUI (that works):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:view="http://<service namespace>">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
                   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
                                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
                                wsu:Id="X509-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254925">(data)</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254928" 
                    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod  Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv view" 
                                    xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#TS-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254624">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse soapenv view" 
                                      xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>hg5n7PfuAfYb/LEawatI4ZBK0wmy14+Y6DihGhgBMI4=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>(data)</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254926">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254927">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254925" 
                            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-F4F47BCAA968D14D08143033737254624">
        <wsu:Created>2015-04-29T19:56:12Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2015-04-29T19:56:17Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>  
  <!-- Not relevant.  Not signed -->
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the message produced by WCF with the specified bindings:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo8j1TaWVCpRLgEy0S8UuwAcBAAAAAkQP7Rrb00auQ0G7/7Q0C1x7YNOf+kFOt9ioJVgbfFYACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
                xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:BinarySecurityToken>
        <!-- Removed-->
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod>
          <Reference URI="#_1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
            <DigestValue>8KAbTZRA1cC60emKdKIiIm3zvv1jPPfVaia3a9l1c3g=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-5cb02cb6-0ae6-486d-ad2b-f9f9107b4576-2">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
            <DigestValue>zR0k1GizuQekuM9WcSzVGssZowuzj3Dza/WGYmMqjSo=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>(data)</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
                         URI="#uuid-96e7c3a3-cbe9-409e-ad49-9dcc07ef4360-2"></o:Reference>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-5cb02cb6-0ae6-486d-ad2b-f9f9107b4576-2">
        <u:Created>2015-04-30T18:00:28.886Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2015-04-30T18:05:28.886Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here are differences/missing items from the WCF version compared to the SoapUI version:

- `<BinarySecurityToken>` missing `EncodingType`, `ValueType` and `Id`
  attributes.
- `<Signature>` missing `Id` attribute.
- 'CanonicalizationMethod`missing`

  `<Reference>` two elements instead of 1.  Not sure what the `URI` attribute is for (in the WCF version).

  `<KeyInfo>` missing `Id` attribute.

  `<SecurityTokenReference>` missing `Id` attribute.

Everything else seems to match up (with the exception of namespace prefixes and where they are assigned).  I would prefer to do this via a custom binding, but I'm open to implementing `IClientMessageInspector` if I need to massage the outgoing request.

Comment: For testing as well as troubleshooting, the following code usually works for me:
            proxy.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(...);
            proxy.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetScopedCertificate(...);     proxy.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
proxy.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

Note: in production environment, setting revocation mode to None/NoCheck may not be recommended

Comment: Thanks @Thuan for your comment.  It did not resolve the issue, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue this morning.  There were 2 issues at hand.

The first appears to be related to my company's VPN.  I was able to send and receive responses yesterday in the office (as opposed to the day I posted the question, when I was on VPN).  Last night on the VPN again I was getting the `There was no endpoint listening at https://<service addres> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.` exception again, so I deployed the client to one of our dev servers and was able to communicate successfully again.

The second issue was discovered once I was able to send the message.  I saw the response in the trace message logs, but I received a new exception:

`Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties. This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.`

The request is signed (by the client), but the response is unsigned.  Setting the `enableUnsecuredResponse` attribute on the custom binding to `true` resolved this issue.

The final custom binding configuration looks like this:

```
<customBinding>
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="1.1" />
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
              defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Sha256Rsa15"
              enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
              includeTimestamp="true"
              messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
              securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast" />
    <httpsTransport /> 
</customBinding>
```

No changes in the code for setting the certificates, with the exception of making the name passed into `EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity` configurable.

Comment: You mean your SOAP UI envelope differs from WCF envelope but they both work?
I'm surprised. Please confirm