# Signing a SOAP request with WCF (or other .NET stuff)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to talk with some external WebServices, using SOAP with XML Signature (xmldsig), over HTTPS.

WCF seems to be the actual way to do it with .NET/C#. I tried some (many) things, but without success. The signature isn't exactly the same as what's awaited by the remote server, and I always get an invalid signature message (without more information).

I have a "project" with SoapUI which allow me to see what's needed. But I can't get exactly the same thing with WCF. I think I need to use a custom binding, but it's really not obvious, and I'm rather a WCF newbie.

From a message like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:axw="http://www.axway.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <axw:ws_liste_adherents>
        <axw:adherent>XXXXX</axw:adherent>
    </axw:ws_liste_adherents>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With a given certificate (+ password), I have to build a message like this (I replaced some content with `XXXXX`):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:axw="http://www.axway.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-797BAE4CD3371CB59B14999468343185" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="axw soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#id-797BAE4CD3371CB59B14999468343164">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="axw" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>RCb3MTzUAr9dwAlG2ossgryTrTI=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        
        <ds:SignatureValue>NhTdqGTLFdgoXbwehGnWeX+zbz5GDAd2cjT39/5acDstEMjdUt5U4zzc7wsAaHf0skH+M5/yFLF8
        T11aHhCZWaN/RDNg7kP47lvovMFeOwjYx2zs4LLFedAXcKtI7LjQtvA90r2zqYe4JykuD1LbOHjy
        CCiU7ZrPGAsOB4rIyvz3gV3WfWR+MMpjgw6FsZ1ZujSOk4ezNPZk9R0wjm4MPbIHG+hUzQol6J4v
        LYkZQKoMIPDOnz6cYf0RFTnZRBL8cf/Brq5NiN946145yj/+ElYjRzYQvo3Vex4EdZM5S4Rpk1vv
        t+OyKkv5CbBcvrewdlYY/QdtsSakHo5OXcGbcA==</ds:SignatureValue>

        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-797BAE4CD3371CB59B14999468343112">
            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-797BAE4CD3371CB59B14999468343133">
                <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>

        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>

<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-797BAE4CD3371CB59B14999468343164" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <axw:ws_liste_adherents>
        <axw:adherent>XXXX</axw:adherent>
    </axw:ws_liste_adherents>
</soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is really WCF the right tool? Is using a custom binding to right way to do it?

Some help will be welcome, as I'm totally stuck now.

Thanks.

Comment: You will most likely need to use a custom binding - I had to do something along those lines a while back with an external vendor service.  Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006215/745969) to see if it will help you get started - the specifics may vary, but the general idea may help.

Comment: Thanks @Tim . Sorry for the delay, but I didn't worked since my post (Bastille Day in France). Now the staging remote server is down... I'll give a feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: Status : project delayed then cancelled few weeks after my post. So I could not complete this subject with a possible solution. Sorry.