# C# Send a SOAP Message signed with an X.509 certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap, soapui

I am trying to message a SOAP service that requires a X.509 certificate.

In [Soap UI](https://www.soapui.org/) I set the certificate path and password in [SSL settings](https://www.soapui.org/working-with-soapui/reference/preferences-and-settings.html#SSL-Settings), enter the envelope in request window, hit Submit and get the result.

In C# it gets complicated, mostly because I am very new to this stuff. So first I tried writing a simple message sending method using [Send and Receive a SOAP Message By Using the SoapClient and SoapService Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529276.aspx) guide, it works.

Next step would be to sign (I guess) my SOAP message with a certificate, there is a guide for that too, o ar at least a [Sign a SOAP Message Using an X.509 Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529277.aspx) guide, so now I have a class/method that can send SOAP messages and a class/method that can sign SOAP message.

But I have no idea on how to actually sign it, my code looks something like this:

```
public class SOAPTest
{
    public static string Call(string argsUrl, string requestAction, string argsXml)
    {
        Uri destination_uri = new Uri(argsUrl);
        EndpointReference destination = new EndpointReference(destination_uri);
        SoapEnvelope envelope = new SoapEnvelope();

        envelope.LoadXml(argsXml);

        // The destination variable is the EndpointReference 
        // for the Web service.
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(destination);

        SoapEnvelope returnEnvelope = client.RequestResponseMethod(envelope);
        // The envelope that is returned is the response data.

        return returnEnvelope.OuterXml;
    }
}
```

And I have all the classes mentioned in [Sign a SOAP Message Using an X.509 Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529277.aspx) and [Create a Custom Policy Assertion that Secures SOAP Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528788.aspx): CustomSecurityAssertion, CustomSecurityServerInputFilter, CustomSecurityServerOutputFilter, CustomSecurityClientInputFilter and CustomSecurityClientOutputFilter, last one looks like this and as I understand has the `SecureMessage` method that I need to use to sign the envelope:

```
class CustomSecurityClientOutputFilter : SendSecurityFilter
{
    SecurityToken clientToken;
    SecurityToken serverToken;

    public CustomSecurityClientOutputFilter(CustomSecurityAssertion parentAssertion)
        : base(parentAssertion.ServiceActor, true)
    {
        // Get the client security token.
        clientToken = X509TokenProvider.CreateToken(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, "CN=B2B");

        // Get the server security token.
        serverToken = X509TokenProvider.CreateToken(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "CN=B2B");
    }

    public override void SecureMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {
        X509SecurityToken signatureToken = GetSecurityToken("CN=B2B");
        if (signatureToken == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Message Requirements could not be satisfied.");
        }

        // Add the security token.                
        security.Tokens.Add(signatureToken);
        // Specify the security token to sign the message with.
        MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);

        security.Elements.Add(sig);

    }

    public X509SecurityToken GetSecurityToken(string subjectName)
    {
        X509SecurityToken securityToken = null;
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,
          StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        try
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection certs =
                store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
                subjectName, false);

            X509Certificate2 cert;
            if (certs.Count == 1)
            {
                cert = certs[0];
                securityToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert);
            }
            else
                securityToken = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (store != null)
                store.Close();
        }
        return securityToken;
    }
}
```

How do I "connect" these two and get same result I get in Soap UI?

Am I at least doing the right thing trying to sign the message? If I try to run my project as it is I get the following error message:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

But if I supply wrong certificate name I get error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

So it looks like the SOAP message signing works, but server still refuses the connection, however using Soap UI and same certificate and same SOAP envelope everything works without issues, any suggestions?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666970/signing-soap-messages-using-x-509-certificate-from-wcf-service-to-java-webservic?rq=1